# es6 merge two array of objects and override the existing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, ecmascript-6

I have 2 array of objects:

```
const arr1 = [{'id':'1' 'value':'yes'}, {'id':'2', 'value':'no'}];
const arr2 = [{'id':'2', 'value':'yes'}];
```

So, if I try and merge these 2 arrays the result should be:

```
arrTemp = [{'id':'1', 'value':'yes'}, {'id':'2', 'value':'yes'}];
```

Basically, it should work similar to Object.assign(), but no matter what I try it does not work. Could anyone please help me in this ?

I modified the data structure. Is it possible to merge them now and get the output.

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to remove {'2':'no'}?

Comment: This datastrucure is so ugly.

Comment: Why are you using different keys in each object?

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can get the job done with ES6 spread, reduce and Object.values.

```js
const arr1 = [{
  'id': '1',
  'value': 'yes'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'value': 'no'
}];
const arr2 = [{
  'id': '2',
  'value': 'yes'
}];

const result = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((result, {
  id,
  ...rest
}) => {
  result[id] = {
    ...(result[id] || {}),
    id,
    ...rest
  };
  return result;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is really great and is the most up to date answer, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

```
const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...arr1,...arr2)).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]:value}));
```

You could spread (`...`) the arrays into one resulting object ( via `Object.assign`) and then `map` its entries to an array again.

Comment: It throws  uncaughtException: Unexpected token : .I agree the datastructure is ugly, but cant change it now.

Comment: @ashy im sorry, fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, arrays are simply objects indexed by numbers starting from 0.

So when you use `Object.assign` on `arr1` and `arr2` you will override the first item in the `arr1` with the first item in `arr2` because they are both indexed under the key `0`.

your result will be:

```
[
 { '2': 'yes' },
 { '2': 'no' }
]
```

(or in object syntax:)

```
{ 
 0: { '2': 'yes' },
 1: { '2': 'no' }
}
```

Instead of using arrays, you could create an object indexed by the number **string** (which is how you seem to be thinking of the array in any case).

So you could change your original data structure to make the job easier:

```
const arr1 = {
  '1': 'yes',
  '2': 'no'
};

const arr2 = {
  '2': 'yes'
};

const result = Object.assign(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: Why not simply `{ 1:"yes", 2:"false" }` then? *In general I usually prefer using objects to arrays in javascript in most cases.* -> thats the wrong approach. Choose the right one for the right job. Arrays are very very useful.

Comment: it is an array of very big objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could work with a valid ES6 data structure like a map for example:

`const 1 = { 1: { string: 'yes' }, 2:  { string: 'no' } }
const 2 = { 2: { string: 'yes' }, 3: { string: 'no' } }
const 3 = { ...1, ...2}`

This will override your first argument with the second one or just combine them where possible.
Just try it out in your browser it's a lot easier and enhances performance since you will never have to use `findById()` which is an expensive operation.

Comment: *findById()* -> what should that be?! And identifiers cant start with a number!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as reference to the new assigned object in the result array and build first a new array with a copy of the objects and then iterate the second array and update the objects with the same key.

```js
var array1 = [{ 1: 'yes' }, { 2: 'no' }],
    array2 = [{ 2: 'yes' }],
    getKey = o => Object.keys(o)[0],
    map = new Map,
    result = array1.map(o => (k => map.set(k, Object.assign({}, o)).get(k))(getKey(o)));

array2.forEach(o => Object.assign(map.get(getKey(o)), o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array `reduce` could come in handy is this case. See example below:

```
[...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, item) => {
  const updated = acc.find(a => a.id === item.id)
  if (!updated) {
    acc.push(item)
  } else {
    const index = acc.indexOf(updated)
    acc[index] = { ...item, ...acc[index] }
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

simple way to add with exist array of object:

```
const arr1 = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"toyata" }];
const arr2 = [{ "name":"Ales", "age":40, "car":"Nissan" }];
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);

Result:=>
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone finding this answer at a later point in time. There are a couple of ways that you could want this to work exactly, but you could filter all adjusted elements in the first array, and then combine it with the second array.

```
const arr3 = [...arr1.filter(item1 => !arr2.find(item2 => item1.id === item2.id)), ...arr2]
```

Alternatively, you could update the elements in the first array, and then filter them from the second array instead.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use array.prototype map because the key of arr1 and arr2 have the same value '2'.

You should use something like this

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
 var key = Object.keys(arr1[i]);
 if (!arr2[key]) { arr2[key] = []; }
 arr2[key].push(arr1[i][key]);
}
```

Regards