# How can I merge two arrays of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a simple question. I have two arrays A and B, I want to retain A objects if B has the same ID. 
For example:

```
const A = [{id: "price", value: "1"}]

const B = [{id: "price", value: "0"}, {id: "number", value: "0"}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{id: "price", value: "1"}, {id: "number", value: "0"}}]
```

How can I do this?

I tried to map A and foreach B inside A but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to replace `A`'s objects or `B`'s objects? The expected result is confusing

Comment: The term is "merging" and has been covered plenty of times...

Comment: I have edit. Thats right, I want to merge these two arrays into one

Comment: If A and B have same ID, do you want to keep A or B? Your question does not match your expected result.

Comment: _"I want to replace A objects if B has the same ID"_ and the expexcted output don't match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 merge two array of objects and override the existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554688/es6-merge-two-array-of-objects-and-override-the-existing-object)

Comment: @YongQuan I want to keep A.

Comment: Does your environment support ES6? If so, the question @HereticMonkey linked is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const result = A.concat(B.filter(bo => A.every(ao => ao.id != bo.id)));
```

Concatenate all the objects from `A` with objects from `B` that aren't in `A` (which is done by filtering only objects from `B` where there isn't an object in `A` with the same id).

**Example:**

```js
const A = [{id: "price", value: "1"}];

const B = [{id: "price", value: "0"}, {id: "number", value: "0"}];

const result = A.concat(B.filter(bo => A.every(ao => ao.id != bo.id)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `reduce` on the merged array - also turn the `value` into a number:

```js
const A = [{id: "price", value: "1"}];
const B = [{id: "price", value: "0"}, {id: "number", value: "0"}];
const res = Object.values([...A, ...B].reduce((acc, { id, value }) => {
  if (acc[id]) acc[id].value += parseInt(value);
  else acc[id] = { id, value: parseInt(value) };
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: The problem is that my value is not always a number.

Comment: Well then what will your value be? A decimal?

Comment: It can be a number or a string. I want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you could try (I believe it would be O(n) ) is to convert arrays to objects with id as key then extend (jquery.extend or pure js implementation) then convert the merged object back to array.

```js
const A = [{id: "price", value: "1"}];

const B = [{id: "price", value: "0"}, {id: "number", value: "0"}];

//convert arrays to objects
var Bx = {};
B.forEach(i => Bx[i.id] = i);

var Ax = {};
A.forEach(i => Ax[i.id] = i);

//copy all matching id properties from A to B
A.forEach(i => Bx[i.id] = Ax[i.id]);

//convert the merged object to array
var C = [];
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Bx).forEach(i => C.push(Bx[i]));

console.log(C);
```